# Use TypeLib to get names of methods and properties

Tags: c#, com, activex, typelib

I have an ActiveX component which has a detailed Typelib also. Now I want to get the list of methods and properties of this component programatically preferably in C#.
Can anyone guide me how to go about it?

Comment: C# is not the ideal tool for that, ITypeLib isn't that fun to use.  Can't you just use Tlbexp.exe to create the interop library and use Reflection?  Or use the OleView.exe tool to decompile the type library?  What is the point of this in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2112598/868014 explains what it takes to do the enumeration

Comment: Run time? compile time? If compile time, OleView.exe will give you everything. If runtime, let me know, I'll post some code.

Comment: @Uri - I have tied OleView.exe but I want to do it programmatically. So, if you can share some code, it would be great!