# Python - Get list of all attributes/properties of a win32com class

Tags: python, properties, attributes, win32com

I am a newbie in Python. I have to extract emails from Outlook and get all attributes/properties of the emails.

Retrieving properties one by one, for the attributes/properties that I know they exist works fine (.Subject, .Body, etc.).

But, I need to get all possible attributes. That's where my problem is.
I have been looking for hours, the only answers I found were using:

- vars()
- dir()
- inspect.getmembers(obj)
- `__dict__`
- etc.

Which does not give me the list of properties like:

- .Subject
- .Body
- .SentOn
- etc.

Could someone help ?

Here is the extract of my test Notebook :

```
####### Retrieve email from Outlook #######
import win32com.client
objOutlookMAPI=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
​    
​### Define folder
objOlFolder = objOutlookMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)

​### Retrieve ant print email
objOlMessages = objOlFolder.Items
​
# objMessage : class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'
objMessage = objOlMessages.GetLast()
print(objMessage.Subject)    

> Are you going to Las Vegas for Black Hat, DefCon, Bsides, or Hacking Diversity? Either or join us on our adventures!

vars(objMessage)

> {'_builtMethods_': {},
 '_enum_': None,
 '_lazydata_': (<PyITypeInfo at 0x0000021EC7B7D170 with obj at 0x0000021EC7B4B2F8>,
  <PyITypeComp at 0x0000021EC7B7D620 with obj at 0x0000021EC7B4B058>),
 '_mapCachedItems_': {},
 '_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x0000021EC7B7D290 with obj at 0x0000021EC7B4AAA8>,
 '_olerepr_': <win32com.client.build.LazyDispatchItem at 0x21ec8a7ba90>,
 '_unicode_to_string_': None,
 '_username_': 'GetLast'}


    dir(objMessage)
    #import inspect
    #inspect.getmembers(objMessage)

> [`'_ApplyTypes_'`,
 `'_FlagAsMethod'`,
 `'_LazyAddAttr_'`,
 `'_NewEnum'`,
 `'_Release_'`,
 `'__AttrToID__'`,
 `'__LazyMap__'`,
 `'__bool__'`,
 `'__call__'`,
 `'__class__'`,
 `'__delattr__'`,
 `'__dict__'`,
 `'__dir__'`,
 `'__doc__'`,
 `'__eq__'`,
 `'__format__'`,
 `'__ge__'`,
 `'__getattr__'`,
 `'__getattribute__'`,
 `'__getitem__'`,
 `'__gt__'`,
 `'__hash__'`,
 `'__init__'`,
 `'__init_subclass__'`,
 `'__int__'`,
 `'__le__'`,
 `'__len__'`,
 `'__lt__'`,
 `'__module__'`,
 `'__ne__'`,
 `'__new__'`,
 `'__reduce__'`,
 `'__reduce_ex__'`,
 `'__repr__'`,
 `'__setattr__'`,
 `'__setitem__'`,
 `'__sizeof__'`,
 `'__str__'`,
 `'__subclasshook__'`,
 `'__weakref__'`,
 `'_builtMethods_'`,
 `'_enum_'`,
 `'_find_dispatch_type_'`,
 `'_get_good_object_'`,
 `'_get_good_single_object_'`,
 `'_lazydata_'`,
 `'_make_method_'`,
 `'_mapCachedItems_'`,
 `'_oleobj_'`,
 `'_olerepr_'`,
 `'_print_details_'`,
 `'_proc_'`,
 `'_unicode_to_string_'`,
 `'_username_'`,
 `'_wrap_dispatch_'`]
```

Comment: There is likely some magic in `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`.

Comment: So, after further study it appears there is no easy way to introspect the com objects.  You will likely need to use the MSDN documentation, or maybe the VBA debugger.

Comment: In general, COM objects can't enumerate their methods, so there's nothing `win32com` can do about that. But: (1) If it's an `IDispatch` interface that supports `IDispatchEx`, you can just `QueryInterface` to that and call the `GetIDsOfNames` method. (2) If it's an `IDispatch` interface that doesn't do `IDispatchEx`, you can call `GetTypeInfo` on it. (2a) If the resulting `ITypeInfo` supports `ITypeInfo2` you can QI that and enumerate it. (2b) If it doesn't, but it does support `GetTypeAttr` and `GetFuncDesc`, you can use those. (3) If it's none of the above, there is no way.

Comment: Try searching for those method names with `win32com` to see if there are any examples. I didn't find any with a quick search—but I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112302/enumerate-com-object-idispatch-methods-using-atl) for ATL, which covers how to use all those methods, if you know how to translate from C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers guys.
I found also this http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/PythonCOM.html and this
https://www.productiverage.com/idispatch-iwastedtimeonthis-but-ilearntlots. From what I understand there could be the answer of what I am looking for. But it's way over my abilities (like porting C++ into Python).
If nobody has a python code ready, I guess I will have to go through VB and explore the attributes/properties using VBA variable explorer or object explorer...
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity here, I found what I needed in the AppointmentItem object on this page:

[Outlook Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook)

Just expand that object on the left side of the page, and then expand properties.  Found everything I needed there.  Also a MeetingItem object, still in the process of figuring out the difference (which sounds like it's obvious, but a lot of the appointments I'm getting back are actually meetings (i.e. have attendees).

Answer (score 0):

**I found a way to do it, actually:**

The plan is to create a macro in a second presentation that you call from within python and that is, with the help of tlbinf32.dll, able to get all members of an object.

## The Second Presentation

1. To start, you want to [download the `tlbinf32.dll`](https://www.dll-files.com/tlbinf32.dll.html).
   **FOR *64-bit* SYSTEMS:** Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569377/tlbinf32-dll-in-a-64bits-net-application/42581513#42581513) guide to properly set up the 32-bit-DLL! I also had [problems with the `HP Print Scan Doctor Service`](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/error-8004e00f-msdtc-com-hp-print-scan-doctor-service.554455/#Error_8004E00F_MSDTC_COM_HP_Print_Scan_Doctor_Service): I needed to disable that service and uninstall `HP Smart`. (and reboot)
2. Create a new **.pptm** file (pptx with macros) and open it (I named it `GetMembersUtil.pptm`)
3. In that presentation, create a new macro (the name is irrelevant) and edit it (View->Macros)
4. Add a reference to your `tlbinf32.dll` that you just downloaded (Tools->References)
5. Paste the following function after the macro

```vb
Function GetMembers(obj)
    ' Declare vars
    Dim TLI
    Dim TypeInfo
    Dim Members
    
    ' Create new ArrayList since we don't know how many Members obj has
    Set Members = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    ' Initialize tlbinf
    Set TLI = CreateObject("TLI.TLIApplication")
    Set TypeInfo = TLI.InterfaceInfoFromObject(obj)
    
    ' iterate over each Member
    For Each MemberInfo In TypeInfo.Members
        Members.Add MemberInfo.Name
    Next
    
    ' Convert ArrayList back to native vba Array because you can't return an ArrayList
    GetMembers = Members.ToArray()
    
End Function
```

this function takes an object as input and returns all the members of that object

6. Save your presentation in the local directory of your python file

## The Python Side

To be able to use the macro we need to make sure that the presentation we just created is openend

```py
def vba_get_members(app: win32com.client.CDispatch, obj: win32com.client.CDispatch) -> tuple[str, ...]:
    # os.path.abspath is very important
    ensure_opened(app, os.path.abspath("GetMembersUtil.pptm"))
    return app.Run("GetMembersUtil.pptm!GetMembers", obj)

def ensure_opened(app: win32com.client.CDispatch, file_path):
    # check if presentation is already opened
    for presentation in app.Presentations:
        pp_filepath = os.path.join(presentation.Path, presentation.Name)

        if pp_filepath == file_path:
            # presentation already opened
            break
    else:
        # presentation wasn't already opened
        app.Presentations.Open(file_path)
```