# MinGW Hide method names in dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, mingw

I was looking for hiding methods in dlls. In MSVC there is a way to create a def file and link it with the NONAME attribute (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848144/how-to-hide-the-exporting-functions-in-dll)).

Is the same possible in MinGW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a GCC extension, the [visibility attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) :

```
__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
```